# group list based on switching predicate

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to parse a list of lines in Clojure and have the processing pause and start to accumulate if `pred(line)` is true and then stop accumulating when `pred2(laterline)` becomes true.

For example, `pred` will return `True` if value is `b` and then `pred2` is used which returns `True` when the value is `d`

```
[a b c d e f] -> [a [b c d] e f]
```

I feel like the answer must be much simpler and idiomatic than the crazy things I'm coming up with.

Comment: `pred(line)` and `pred2(laterline)` isn't Clojure and this post lacks a question.

Comment: You can use `split-with` to do most of what you want.  See this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028674/how-can-i-group-consecutive-elements-of-list-using-start-stop-predicates/53028726#53028726

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(require '[flatland.useful.seq :refer [partition-between]])
(letfn [(pred [x] (= x 'b))
        (pred2 [x] (= x 'd))]
    (let [A '[a b c d e f g h b d x]]
        (->> A
             (partition-between (fn [[a b]]
                                    (or (pred b)
                                        (pred2 a))))
             (reduce
                 (fn [acc v]
                     (if (pred (first v))
                         (conj acc v)
                         (vec (concat acc v))))
                 []))))
```

produces:

```
=> [a [b c d] e f g h [b d] x]
```

Comment: I went with this in the end. It's still more complex than I anticipated and pulls in a library, but it's a shallow dependency and has some interesting other utilities I may use.