# How can I group consecutive elements of list using start/stop predicates?

Tags: clojure

Suppose I have a list like:

```
(def data [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :b :d :x])
```

and predicates like:

```
(defn start? [x] (= x :b))
(defn stop?  [x] (= x :d))
```

that mark the first & last elements of a sub-sequence.  I want to return a list with subgroups like so:

```
(parse data) => [:a [:b :c :d] :e :f :g :h [:b :d] :x]
```

How can I use Clojure to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 7):

You could use a custom stateful transducer:

```
(defn subgroups [start? stop?]
  (let [subgroup (volatile! nil)]
    (fn [rf]
      (fn
        ([] (rf))
        ([result] (rf result))
        ([result item]
         (let [sg @subgroup]
           (cond
             (and (seq sg) (stop? item))
             (do (vreset! subgroup nil)
               (rf result (conj sg item)))
             (seq sg)
             (do (vswap! subgroup conj item)
               result)
             (start? item)
             (do (vreset! subgroup [item])
               result)
             :else (rf result item))))))))

(into []
      (subgroups #{:b} #{:d})
      [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :b :d :x])
; => [:a [:b :c :d] :e :f :g :h [:b :d] :x]
```

Answer (score 4):

I like the [stateful transducer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53031024/8746216), but noticed the question doesn't say what the behavior should be if a *start* element is found but no *stop* element is found. If a subgroup is left *open* the transducer will truncate the input sequence, which might be unexpected/undesirable. Consider the example with *stop* elements removed:

```
(into [] (subgroups #{:b} #{:d}) [:a :b :c :e :f :g :h :b :x])
=> [:a] ;; drops inputs from before (last) subgroup opens
```

Transducers have a *completing* arity that could be used to flush any open subgroup in this case:

> Completion (arity 1) - some processes will not end, but for those that do (like transduce), the completion arity is used to produce a final value and/or flush state. This arity must call the xf completion arity exactly once.

The only difference in this example and the original transducer example is the *completing* arity:

```
(defn subgroups-all [start? stop?]
  (let [subgroup (volatile! nil)]
    (fn [rf]
      (fn
        ([] (rf))
        ([result] ;; completing arity flushes open subgroup
         (let [sg @subgroup]
           (if (seq sg)
             (do (vreset! subgroup nil)
                 (rf result sg))
             (rf result))))
        ([result item]
         (let [sg @subgroup]
           (cond
             (and (seq sg) (stop? item))
             (do (vreset! subgroup nil)
                 (rf result (conj sg item)))
             (seq sg)
             (do (vswap! subgroup conj item)
                 result)
             (start? item)
             (do (vreset! subgroup [item])
                 result)
             :else (rf result item))))))))
```

Then dangling, open groups will be flushed:

```
(into [] (subgroups-all #{:b} #{:d}) [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :b :x])
=> [:a [:b :c :d] :e :f :g :h [:b :x]]
(into [] (subgroups-all #{:b} #{:d}) [:a :b :c :e :f :g :h :b :x])
=> [:a [:b :c :e :f :g :h :b :x]]
```

*Notice in the last example that nested starts/opens don't result in nested groupings, which got me thinking about another solution...*

## Nested groups and zippers

When I thought about this more generally as "unflattening" a sequence, zippers came to mind:

```
(defn unflatten [open? close? coll]
  (when (seq coll)
    (z/root
     (reduce
      (fn [loc elem]
        (cond
          (open? elem)
          (-> loc (z/append-child (list elem)) z/down z/rightmost)
          (and (close? elem) (z/up loc))
          (-> loc (z/append-child elem) z/up)
          :else (z/append-child loc elem)))
      (z/seq-zip ())
      coll))))
```

This creates a zipper on an empty list and builds it up using `reduce` over the input sequence. It takes a pair of predicates for opening/closing groups and allows for arbitrarily nested groups:

```
(unflatten #{:b} #{:d} [:a :b :c :b :d :d :e :f])
=> (:a (:b :c (:b :d) :d) :e :f)
(unflatten #{:b} #{:d} [:a :b :c :b :d :b :b :d :e :f])
=> (:a (:b :c (:b :d) (:b (:b :d) :e :f)))
(unflatten #{:b} #{:d} [:b :c :e :f])
=> ((:b :c :e :f))
(unflatten #{:b} #{:d} [:d :c :e :f])
=> (:d :c :e :f)
(unflatten #{:b} #{:d} [:c :d])
=> (:c :d)
(unflatten #{:b} #{:d} [:c :d :b])
=> (:c :d (:b))
```

Answer (score 2):

If performance is not an issue, I would use [clojure.spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) for this. First you define a grammar for the data you want to parse:

```
(ns playground.startstop
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as spec]))

(defn start? [x] (= x :b))
(defn stop?  [x] (= x :d))

(spec/def ::not-start-stop #(and (not (start? %))
                                 (not (stop? %))))

(spec/def ::group (spec/cat :start start?
                            :contents (spec/* ::not-start-stop)
                            :stop stop?))

(spec/def ::element (spec/alt :group ::group
                              :primitive ::not-start-stop))

(spec/def ::elements (spec/* ::element))
```

Now you can use the `conform` function to parse your data:

```
(def data [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :b :d :x])

(spec/conform ::elements data)
;; => [[:primitive :a] [:group {:start :b, :contents [:c], :stop :d}] [:primitive :e] [:primitive :f] [:primitive :g] [:primitive :h] [:group {:start :b, :stop :d}] [:primitive :x]]
```

The above output is not what we want, so we define function to render the result:

```
(defn render [[type data]]
  (case type
    :primitive data
    :group `[~(:start data) ~@(:contents data) ~(:stop data)]))
```

And map it over the parsed data:

```
(mapv render (spec/conform ::elements data))
;; => [:a [:b :c :d] :e :f :g :h [:b :d] :x]
```

This spec-based solution is probably not the fastest code, but it is easy to understand, maintain, extend and debug.

Answer (score 1):

The Clojure function `split-with` can be used to do most of the work.  The only tricky bit is to make the subgroup include the `stop?` value as well. Here is one solution:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core demo.core tupelo.test))

(def data [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :b :d :x])

(defn start? [x] (= x :b))
(defn stop?  [x] (= x :d))

(defn parse [vals]
  (loop [result []
         vals   vals]
    (if (empty? vals)
      result
      (let [[singles group-plus]  (split-with #(not (start? %)) vals)
            [grp* others*]        (split-with #(not (stop? %)) group-plus)
            grp        (glue grp* (take 1 others*))
            others     (drop 1 others*)
            result-out (cond-it-> (glue result singles)
                         (not-empty? grp) (append it grp))]
        (recur result-out others)))))
```

With result:

```
(parse data) => [:a [:b :c :d] :e :f :g :h [:b :d] :x]
```

We use `t/glue` and `t/append` so we can [always deal with vectors and append only at the end](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#adding-values-to-the-beginning-or-end-of-a-sequence) (not the beginning like `conj` does with lists).

---

### Update

The use of `cond-it->` at the end to avoid gluing on an empty `[]` vector is a bit ugly.  It occurred to me later that this was a form of mutual recursion that would be ideal for the `trampoline` function:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core demo.core tupelo.test))

(def data [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :b :d :x])

(defn start? [x] (= x :b))
(defn stop?  [x] (= x :d))

(declare parse-singles parse-group)

(defn parse-singles [result vals]
  (if (empty? vals)
    result
    (let [[singles groupies] (split-with #(not (start? %)) vals)
          result-out (glue result singles)]
      #(parse-group result-out groupies))))

(defn parse-group [result vals]
  (if (empty? vals)
    result
    (let [[grp-1 remaining] (split-with #(not (stop? %)) vals)
          grp      (glue grp-1 (take 1 remaining))
          singlies (drop 1 remaining)
          result-out   (append result grp)]
      #(parse-singles result-out singlies))))

(defn parse [vals]
  (trampoline parse-singles [] vals))

(dotest
  (spyx (parse data)))

(parse data) => [:a [:b :c :d] :e :f :g :h [:b :d] :x]
```

Note that for any reasonable size parsing task (say less than a few thousand calls to `parse-singles` and `parse-group` you really don't need to use `trampoline`.  In this case, just remove the `#` from the two calls to `parse-singles` and `parse-group`, and delete `trampoline` from the definition of `parse`.

---

### Clojure CheatSheet

As always, don't forget to [bookmark the Clojure CheatSheet!](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that uses lazy-seq and split-with.
The key is to think about what needs to be produced for each element in the sequence, in this case the pseudo code looks like:

```
;; for each element (e) in the input sequence

if (start? e) 
  (produce values up to an including (stop? e))
else 
  e
```

The Clojure code to implement it isn't much longer that the description above.

```
(def data [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :b :d :x])

(def start? #(= :b %))
(def stop?  #(= :d %))

(defn parse [vals]
  (when-let [e (first vals)]
    (let [[val rst] (if (start? e)
                      (let [[run remainder] (split-with (complement stop?) vals)]
                        [(concat run [(first remainder)]) (rest remainder)])
                      [e (rest vals)])]
      (cons val (lazy-seq (parse rst))))))

;; this produces the following output
(parse data) ;; => (:a (:b :c :d) :e :f :g :h (:b :d) :x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn start? [x] (= x :b))
(defn stop?  [x] (= x :d))
(def data [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :b :d :c])
```

It looks like `split-with` should be a good choice, but meh

```
(loop [data data
       res []]
  (let [[left tail] (split-with (comp not start?) data)
        [group [stop & new-data]] (split-with (comp not stop?) tail)
        group (cond-> (vec group) stop (into [stop]))
        new-res (cond-> (into res left)
                  (seq group) (into [group]))]
    (if (seq new-data)
      (recur new-data new-res)
      new-res)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because I like FSM and quick-bench.

```
(let [start? #(= % :b)
          stop?  #(= % :d)
          data   [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :b :d :x]]
        (letfn [(start [result [x & xs]]
                    #(collect-vec (conj result [x]) xs))

                (collect-vec [result [x & xs]]
                    #(if (nil? x)
                         result
                         ((if (stop? x) initial collect-vec)
                             (conj (subvec result 0 (dec (count result))) (conj (last result) x)) xs)))

                (collect [result [x & xs]]
                    #(initial (conj result x) xs))

                (initial [result [x & xs :as v]]
                    (cond (nil? x) result
                          (start? x) #(start result v)
                          :else (fn [] (collect result v))))]
            (trampoline initial [] data)))
```